# gremlin query to remove one of the value from property

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I am trying to find a way to delete a specific value in a property(list of strings) on a vertex. The vertex has multiple properties and one of the property is a list of strings.

e.g

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('ACCOUNT').or(has('Name', '123')).properties()
==>vp[Value->a]
==>vp[Value->b]
==>vp[Value->c]
```

for e.g I am looking for a query to remove property value 'a' from the list and after the operation the o/p of about query listed should be.

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('ACCOUNT').or(has('Name', '123')).properties()
==>vp[Value->b]
==>vp[Value->c]
```

I am using neo4j as my database.

Answer (score 3):

You can traverse to the vertex properties then filter on the matching value then drop those properties. Also refer to the [vertex property examples](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#vertex-properties) in the TinkerPop documentation.

```
gremlin> Gremlin.version()
==>3.2.9
gremlin> // create the vertices
gremlin> g.addV('ACCOUNT').
......1>     property(list, 'Value', 'a').
......2>     property(list, 'Value', 'b').
......3>     property(list, 'Value', 'c').
......4>     iterate()
gremlin> g.addV('PERSON').
......1>     property('Name', '123').
......2>     property(list, 'Value', 'a').
......3>     property(list, 'Value', 'b').
......4>     property(list, 'Value', 'c').
......5>     iterate()

gremlin> // show all properties (before)
gremlin> g.V().or(hasLabel('ACCOUNT'), has('Name', '123')).
......1>     project('label', 'props').
......2>     by(label()).by(properties().fold())
==>[label:ACCOUNT,props:[vp[Value->a],vp[Value->b],vp[Value->c]]]
==>[label:PERSON,props:[vp[Value->a],vp[Value->b],vp[Value->c],vp[Name->123]]]

gremlin> // drop only the matching property
gremlin> g.V().or(hasLabel('ACCOUNT'), has('Name', '123')).properties('Value').
......1>     hasValue('a').
......2>     drop().iterate()

gremlin> // show all properties (after)
gremlin> g.V().or(hasLabel('ACCOUNT'), has('Name', '123')).
......1>     project('label', 'props').
......2>     by(label()).by(properties().fold())
==>[label:ACCOUNT,props:[vp[Value->b],vp[Value->c]]]
==>[label:PERSON,props:[vp[Value->b],vp[Value->c],vp[Name->123]]]
```

Comment: He actually has only one vertex in his example, the `Name` property is related to the `ACCOUNT` vertex. The `or()` step is pointless and added to the confusion. Also, you don't need a lambda-filter step, it's just `...properties('Value').hasValue('a')`,

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I'll update the answer with `hasValue('a')`. The original question didn't have a `Name` property on the vertex at all, otherwise it would have been listed as one of the properties in the result. That's why I created 2 separate vertices in my example ;)